# How to have a proper breadcrumb path

Tags: 7, path-aliases, breadcrumbs

I have a problem with my breadcrumb path on my drupal 7 installation. I am using URL-Alias (Module: pathauto) and have a "blog" content type.
Now the view with all blog entries in the URL is on /blogs/ and entries are like /blogs/entryname.
Unfortunately the breadcrumb still shows: frontsite / entryname no matter what I do instead of frontsite / blogs / entryname.

Same goes for taxonomy terms. I have an overview over taxonomy terms which is on /tags/ and when I click on a certain tag on that overview, i get a view with all nodes associated with that tag and the URL is like /tags/tagname but breadcrumbs still show frontsite / tagname instead of frontsite / tags / tagname.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Which Drupal version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I used a module called Smart Breadcrumb that builds breadcrumbs by using the url path and determining the title for each page. So far its Drupal 7 only.
https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_breadcrumb

Comment: This sounds very much the same idea as Easy Breadcrumb, https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb. Are you aware of any advantages of either module?